# Create Graphic from hDC results in arithmetic operation overflow

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I attempt to prepare printing document by using WinAPI instead of (System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument) because Graphic.DrawString does not render Khmer Unicode properly. Only TextRendering.DrawText renders it properly. I believe Graphic is GDI+ wrapper and TextRendering.DrawText is using GDI. Furthermore, PrintDocument does not work with TextRendering.DrawText.

```
Private Declare Function CreateDC Lib "gdi32" Alias "CreateDCA" _
(ByVal lpDriverName As String, ByVal lpDeviceName As String, _
 ByVal lpOutput As String, ByVal lpInitData As DEVMODE) As Long
Private Declare Function EndDoc Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function StartDoc Lib "gdi32" Alias "StartDocA" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal lpdi As DOCINFO) As Long
Private Declare Function StartPage Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EndPage Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    '' Getting Printer hDC
    Dim printHandler As Long = CreateDC(Nothing, "Send To OneNote 2010", Nothing, Nothing)
    Dim docInfo As New DOCINFO
    docInfo.cbSize = Len(docInfo)
    docInfo.lpszDatatype = Nothing
    docInfo.lpszOutput = Nothing
    docInfo.lpszDocName = "Testing"

    StartDoc(printHandler, docInfo)
    StartPage(printHandler)

    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromHdc(printHandler)
    TextRenderer.DrawText(g, "Hello World", Me.Font, New Point(10, 10), Color.Black)

    EndPage(printHandler)
    EndDoc(printHandler)
End Sub
```

Here is my attempt. It fails on this line of code: `Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromHdc(printHandler)`. It seem like Long is 64-bits and IntPtr is 32-bits.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Why have you declared `CreateDC` to return a `Long`?  The API returns an `HDC` so use `IntPtr`.

Comment: I have already tried IntPtr before I asked this question. When I used Long, it opened OneNote 2010 as printer. When I used IntPtr, it does not do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your P/Invoke definitions are wrong for VB.NET. You've obviously copied them from a project or website targeting VB 6, but lots of things have changed with .NET.

The correct definitions look like:

```
<DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function CreateDC(lpszDriver As String, _
                                 lpszDevice As String, _
                                 lpszOutput As IntPtr, _
                                 ByRef lpInitData As DEVMODE) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError:=False)> _
Private Shared Function EndDoc(hdc As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError:=False)> _
Private Shared Function StartDoc(hdc As IntPtr, ByRef lpdi As DOCINFO) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError:=False)> _
Private Shared Function StartPage(hdc As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError:=False)> _
Private Shared Function EndPage(hdc As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function
```

And chances are good that your definitions for the `DEVMODE` and `DOCINFO` structures are wrong, as well. You're probably using `Long` instead of `IntPtr` for pointer types, and mixing up `Long` and `Integer` for numeric types, since the meaning of those types changed from VB 6 to VB.NET.

You probably don't need the `DEVMODE` structure at all, and if so, you can replace the `CreateDC` function definition with:

```
<DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function CreateDC(lpszDriver As String, _
                                 lpszDevice As String, _
                                 lpszOutput As IntPtr, _
                                 lpInitData As IntPtr) As IntPtr _
End Function
```

and pass `IntPtr.Zero` for `lpInitData`, just like you will for `lpszOutput`, as instructed by [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183490.aspx)—`IntPtr.Zero` is effectively equivalent to `NULL` for pointer types.

The `DOCINFO` structure would be declared as:

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Structure DOCINFO
    Dim cbSize As Integer
    Dim lpszDocName As String
    Dim lpszOutput As String
    Dim lpszDatatype As String
    Dim fwType As Integer
End Structure
```

As per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183574.aspx), the `fwType` member can be any of the following constants:

- 0
- `Private Const DI_APPBANDING As Integer = &H1`
- `Private Const DI_ROPS_READ_DESTINATION As Integer = &H2`

---

All of that said…you do know there are easier ways of printing things in the world of .NET, right?

Comment: I do know the easier. Using PrintDocument and its PrintPage event. The point is that PrintDocument does not work with TextRendering. I have changed everything that you suggested. CreateDC returns null. I will try to fix it. (If I couldn't fix on my own, I will come here again) Cheer.

Comment: @invisal I can't tell you what's wrong with your call to `CreateDC` without knowing what arguments you're passing to the function. When it returns `NULL`, that's a sign that the function failed. Make sure you check [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183490.aspx) and ensure that you're passing valid arguments. (Also I forgot to include in my answer that **you must call the [`DeleteDC` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183533.aspx) to destroy the device context you create with `CreateDC` after you're finished with it, otherwise you'll leak memory**.)